# How can I set the minDate/maxDate for jQueryUI Datepicker using a string?

Tags: string, jquery-ui, datepicker, mindate, maxdate

jQueryUI Datepicker [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) states that the minDate option can be set using "a string in the current dateFormat". So I've tried the following to initialize datepickers:

```
$("input.date").datepicker({ minDate: "01/01/2010", maxDate: "12/31/2010" });
```

However, this results in my datepicker having a selectable date range that goes from 11/06/2015 to 12/17/2015.

I've checked the current dateformat and its `mm/dd/yy`, which is supposed to mean 2 digits for the month, 2 for the day, and 4 for the year, separated by slashes. I've also tried including `dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"` in the inizialization statement.

I've also checked the values for minDate and maxDate afterwards and they ARE being set to the values I want: `01/01/2010` and `12/31/2010`.

I want to be able to set min/maxDate with strings because I'm being passed these values as strings from somewhere else. Maybe someone knows why this happens and how to solve this, or a workaround to achieve this, perphaps changing the format of the date strings or something?

Thanks

EDIT:
Using: **jQuery v1.3.2** and **jQuery UI v1.7.2**

Comment: I think mm/dd/yy means more-like 12/31/10 (2 digits for years)

Comment: Nope... 'y' means 2 digits for year while 'yy' means 4. See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I had to use something like this, since the v1.7 datepicker has no probs with Dates:

```
$.getJSON("/GetMinMaxDates/", function(dates) {
    var DateLimits = {min:null, max:null};

    DateLimits.min = new Date(Date.parse(dates.min));
    DateLimits.max = new Date(Date.parse(dates.max));

    $("input.date").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", minDate: DateLimits.min, maxDate: DateLimits.max });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a "bug" in 1.3.2 with 1.7.2.  In 1.4.2 with 1.8.1 all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found your last method to be best for IE7/8 anyway.  IE returns NaN in string-fed Date functions; as soon as I parsed to numbers the problem disappeared.