# jQuery date sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript date sorting by convert the string in to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365116/javascript-date-sorting-by-convert-the-string-in-to-date-format)

I am not good in jquery so I was wondering if there is a way or plugin I can use to sort date divs. I have date in YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS format. I am displaying date in divs as shown below. Divs are in unordered format and I want to sort them on latest date first basis.

```
<div id="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div>
<div id="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div>
<div id="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div>
<div id="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769301/how-can-i-set-the-mindate-maxdate-for-jqueryui-datepicker-using-a-string  Looks similar to yours.

Comment: As a side note, using duplicate `id`s is a big no-no.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan: Sorry my mistake. I haven't used duplicate id in actual code I just did copy paste of same dive here in the exmple for the sake of convinience.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know much about plugins...although if you want a light weight method without plugins, you may try this:

html:

```
<div id="D">
    <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div>
    <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div>
    <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div>
    <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div>
</div>
```

For js:

```
var elems = $.makeArray($(".dateDiv"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date( $(a).text() ) < new Date( $(b).text() );
});
$("#D").html(elems);
```

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to CMS for answering this question about parsing dates: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]); //     months are 0-based
}

var elems = $.makeArray($(".dateDiv"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log( parseDate( $(a).text() ) );
    return parseDate( $(a).text() ) < parseDate( $(b).text() );
});
$("#D").html(elems);​
```

Now, don't tell me this doesn't work...hehe

Comment: This won't work - this is not a valid string for Date constructor.

Comment: I don't know why...but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/jCkCP/

Comment: It doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/WpTb5/1/ Maybe it's browser / OS dependent?

Comment: i've updated the answer...this should definitely work

Comment: Nope... console.log(Date.parse( $(a).text() ));//NaN. UPDATE: That's browser dependent: works in Chrome, doesn't in Firefox.

Comment: In theory, there's no reason to parse out a date since the format used will always sort as text just fine.  Not very futureproof, but it will work...

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [date.js](http://datejs.com) library combined with [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) sorter function to do this:

```
$('#dateDiv').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return Date.parse($(a).text()) > Date.parse($(b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

The original repo has not been maintained, but an updated fork of it appears to be in progress [here](http://github.com/datejs/Datejs).

Comment: This worked well for me but I found the Date.js was much slower parsing the dates than using the parseDate function by Parth Thakkar above. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: That library was last updated 9 years ago.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac see https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

Comment: updated link to indicate this