# Javascript/jQuery nested array sort

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array like this:

```
var arr = [
    ["2013/09/09", 1, 2], 
    ["2013/12/31", 2, 5], 
    ["2014/12/30", 1, 4], 
    ["2013/04/17", 1, 1]
];
```

I need to sort this array according to date present in each of the sub-arrays.

ex.

```
var sorted = [
    ["2013/04/17", 1, 1], 
    ["2013/09/09", 1, 2], 
    ["2013/12/31", 2, 5], 
    ["2014/12/30", 1, 4]
];
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Comment: here is also a link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636779/jquery-date-sorting ==> now in this SO old question people have written Sort for date picker, all you need is to reuse the code `:)` hope this helps.

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: All the possible duplicate suggestions mentioned here are array of objects not multi-dimensional array. The very close one could be the `jquery-date-sorting`. But is still not close enough to replicate the same problem as mentioned in this OP. +1 for non-reasonable downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sorting large arrays, its better to do a date conversion just once, 
  rather than repeating the creation on every jiggle of the sort routine.

```
    function unaturalSort(arr){
        var T= arr.slice(0), L= T.length, i, itm, next;
        // create a timestamp for each element
        for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
            itm= T[i];
            next= T[i][0];
            T[i]= [+new Date(next), itm];
        }
        T.sort(function(a, b){
            return a[0]-b[0]
        });
        //remove the timestamps from the sorted array
        for(i= 0; i<L; i++){
            T[i]= T[i][1];
        }
        return T;
    }

    var A= [
        ["2013/09/09", 1, 2], ["2013/12/31", 2, 5], 
        ["2014/12/30", 1, 4],["2013/04/17", 1, 1]
    ];


    unaturalSort(A).join('\n'); 

 returned value: (String)
    2013/04/17, 1, 1
    2013/09/09, 1, 2
    2013/12/31, 2, 5
    2014/12/30, 1, 4
```

Note- skip the slice(), if you mean to rearrange the existing array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var arr = [
    ["2013/09/09", 1, 2], 
    ["2013/12/31", 2, 5], 
    ["2014/12/30", 1, 4], 
    ["2013/04/17", 1, 1]
];

var temp;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
    {
        var di = new Date(arr[i][0]);
        var dj = new Date(arr[j][0]);

        if(di < dj)
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of native `sort` and `parseInt` which I believe I am the most short hand among the other answers:

```
function sortDate (a,b){
       return parseInt(a[0].split("/").join("")) - parseInt(b[0].split("/").join(""));
}

var arr = [
    ["2013/09/09", 1, 2], 
    ["2013/12/31", 2, 5], 
    ["2014/12/30", 1, 4], 
    ["2013/04/17", 1, 1]
];

var result = arr.sort(sortDate)

console.log(result);
```