# Sorting LI elements w.r.t Datetime attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet for `li` tag:

```
tl = '<li>';
    tl+= '<time class="cbp_tmtime" datetime="2013-04-10 18:30"><span>04/10/13</span> <span>18:30</span></time>';
    tl+= '<div class="cbp_tmlabel">';
    tl+= '<p>TL Content Goes here</p>';
    tl+= '</div>';
    tl+= '</li>';
```

As you can see there's a `time` tag. Is it possible to use jQuery to sort `<ul>` based w.r.t `datetime` attribute?

Comment: can you provide the rendered html.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is.

You can write a sort for them: [How to define custom sort function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002848/how-to-define-custom-sort-function-in-javascript)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58eyg7ds/1/ and the code used to create a custom sort for jQuery:

```
$.fn.sortMyData = function() {
  var elements = $(this).find('> *');

  // Create an array for the content
  var arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elements.eq(i));
  }

  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date(a.attr('datetime').replace(/([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}) /, '$1T'))
    var dateB = new Date(b.attr('datetime').replace(/([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}) /, '$1T'))

    if (dateA < dateB) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (dateA > dateB) {
      return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(this).append(arr[i]);
  }
}

$('ul').sortMyData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10637045/3920237), you should be able to do something like this.

```js
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], parts[3], parts[4], parts[5]); //     months are 0-based
}

var elems = $.makeArray($(".dateDiv"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    // Ascending order
    return parseDate( $(a).attr("datetime") ) > parseDate( $(b).attr("datetime") );
});
$("#D").html(elems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="D">
    <div class="dateDiv" datetime="2012-04-15 10:25:45">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div>
    <div class="dateDiv" datetime="2012-04-10 19:41:08">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div>
    <div class="dateDiv" datetime="2012-04-20 07:00:10">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div>
    <div class="dateDiv" datetime="2012-04-12 16:45:50">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. However you can pass entire date `2013-04-10 18:30` in `Date()` constructor and it will split it anyway

Comment: @Volatil3 but passing that to the constructor will lead into an undefined date on Safari and Internet Explorer - Chrome accepts it though. It must include the T to separate time from the date.

Comment: This answer also doesn't use the jQuery wrapper to DOM and doesn't provide a full answer.